# Update value in website odoo

Tags: javascript, python, xml, controller, odoo

I want to update a value after changing another value
for example in the addition to the odoo basket if the quantity is available it shows me a value like the image
[image]

if I increase the quantity I want it to change to not available
 like this 
[image]

This my code source

```
<template id="assets_frontend" inherit_id="website.assets_frontend" name="Shop">
    <xpath expr="." position="inside">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/website_sale_available/static/src/js/website_sale_available.js"></script>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='/website_sale_available/static/src/css/website_sale_available.css'/>
    </xpath>
</template>

<!-- priority 99 for compatibility with sale options, first load sale options view and then this one -->
<template id="cart" inherit_id="website_sale.cart_lines" priority="99">
    <xpath expr="//table[@id='cart_products']//thead/tr" position="inside">
        <th  width="40">Disponibilité</th>
        <th  width="10"></th>
    </xpath>

    <xpath expr="//t[@t-as='line']/tr" position="inside">
        <td width="50" style="color: #0000ff00; font-size: 10px;" class="text-right">

            <t t-if="line.product_id.virtual_available &gt; 0">
              <div class="badge btn stock_label" style="background-color:green;opacity: 0.6;filter: alpha(opacity=60);">
                <span>Disponible</span>
              </div>
            </t>
            <t t-if="line.product_id.virtual_available &lt;= 0" style="background-color:red;">
              <div class="badge btn stock_label" style="background-color:red;opacity: 0.6;filter: alpha(opacity=60);">Epuisé</div>
            </t>
        </td>

        <td  width="10" style="color: #0000ff00; font-size: 0px;" name="virtual_available" >
            <t t-esc="line.product_id.virtual_available"/>
      </td>
    </xpath>
</template>
```